# Error during the layout setup of ECB in Emacs

Tags: emacs, ide, elisp, emacs24, emacs-ecb

Using the CEDET that comes with Emacs 24.3.1 and the ECB that is in Melpa, I get the following message trying - ecb-activate:

```
All requirements for ECB 2.40 fulfilled - Enjoy it!
The ECB is now deactivated.
ecb-clean-up-after-activation-failure: 
ECB 2.40: Errors during the layout setup of ECB.
(error-type: void-function, error-data: (ecb-layout-function-emcas))
```

My setup for ECB in .emacs file is

```
(require 'ecb)
(require 'ecb-autoloads)
;(setq ecb-examples-bufferinfo-buffer-name nil)
(setq ecb-layout-name "emcas")
(setq ecb-show-sources-in-directories-buffer 'always)
(setq ecb-compile-window-height 12)

                    ; ecb keybinds
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-;") 'ecb-activate)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-'") 'ecb-deactivate)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-:") 'ecb-show-ecb-windows)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C->") 'ecb-hide-ecb-windows)
;;; quick navigation between ecb windows
(global-set-key (kbd "C-)") 'ecb-goto-window-edit1)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-!") 'ecb-goto-window-directories)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-@") 'ecb-goto-window-sources)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-#") 'ecb-goto-window-methods)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-$") 'ecb-goto-window-compilation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is with this line:

```
(setq ecb-layout-name "emcas")
```

According to the source:

```
Currently available layouts:
+ Left layouts:   left1 left2 left3 left4 left5 left6 left7 left8 left9 left10 left11 left12   left13 left14 left15
+ Right layouts:   right1
+ Top layouts:   top1 top2
+ Left-right layouts:   leftright1 leftright2 leftright3
```

So it seems like `emcas` is not a valid option, which is hinted at in the error message: `(error-type: void-function, error-data: (ecb-layout-function-emcas))` note the end is `emcas`.